# Do I have to use shared vertices in mesh in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader

I want to create procedurally generated landscape meshes with a flat shaded look in Unity3D.

I thought it would be the best to create **three unique vertices** per triangle and use one calculated normal for the vertices. Building this mesh would lead to redundant vertex position information. (Would it have an impact on render time?)

Anyway... the problem is that I would like to use shading techniques e.g. ambient occlusion on this mesh. I don't want to mess up the mesh topology that Unity3D expects for its shaders.

Is it better to create the meshwith shared vertices, add perhaps a custom vertex attribute e.g. 'flat_normal' and customize the shaders to use this?

Comment: I think that in absolute majority of situations GPU has more processing power available than CPU. The only way to find out is to test both scenarios, I guess. I'd love to see the profiler stats on this one.

Comment: "redundant vertex position information" ?  there's no such thing.  There's absolutely no reason, at all, you need to share vertices in a mesh.

Comment: purely FWIW, (1) it's commonplace to build a mesh to use as a landscape (often totally unnecessary, but no big deal).  (2) you want a "flat, cartoony" look. no problem at all, just click through the many flat-cartoony shaders available (there's a vast selection out there) to get a look you like.  it's worth noting that (3) Unity entirely includes a "terrain" system which these days is really quite good.  you can just trivially use that and the whole job's done.  (Again just select the shader look you want.)

Comment: Hi Nika.  Hmm, on the processing side, it would be really bizarre if there was any performance difference using shared versus ordinary verts.  (I mean, it's just "an array".  The shader says "item 3,178" and gets a position.  What possible difference would it make if the array has 4000 versus 6000 entries??)  From commonplace experience, there's no difference in the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is

## No,

Unity does not, in the slightest, "look for" shared verts. No 3D pipeline has anything to do with shared verts.  Shared verts does not help or hinder the 3D pipeline in anyway at all.

(Very often, when for example we are making dynamic mesh, we just "never use shared verts at all" because, as you have probably found, it's often far simpler to *not* use shared verts.)

The one and only reason to use shared verts is if, for some reason, it happens to make it more convenient for you.  In that case the 3D pipeline (Unity or elsewhere) "allows" shared verts, with no downside.

Comment: BTW, for the record it's worth noting that: it takes maybe three lines of code to convert between shared / unshared verts.  If (for some reason) you wanted to, just have a pass at the end which "shares" (or "de-shares") the verts.  (It will make no difference to the rendering pipeline; it may be easier for you for some other reason.)

Comment: actually there are cases where you cannot have shared vertices and that is when you either want a sharp edge (= the vertex normals have to be different) or you have an UV seam (= the uv coords need to be differnt) or you want adjacent faces receive different vertex colors.

Comment: true, an excellent point. if you consider that the same mesh, then yes sometimes you ***need*** to use ***non***-shared mesh.  Again in terms of the question here, this absolutely emphasizes that the OP certainly does not need to use shared verts.  The key to this QA is that the OP mentions *" I don't want to mess up the mesh topology that Unity3D expects for its shaders"* .. which is absolutely incorrect; the 3D pipeline is "stateless" for triangles, there is never a need to share verts.

Comment: if i understand what he wants correctly, i guess he even has to use individual vertices as he wants it flat shaded, so every vertex of a face needs to point in the same direction or the face normal will "bend" towards the edges and corners. (its probably possible to counter that in a shader, but thatd be kinda backwards and excessive from a computational perspective if you could have the data correct in the first place aswell)

Answer (score 2):

There might be 2 considerations for using shared vertices:

- To reduce memory usage. (Only slightly, but if you need less UV1's, UV2's, normals, vertices it can add up)
- to make it more convenient to share normals. (You only have to alter one normal of a vertex if you want to keep the surface smooth. )

These are no big reasons, but as most of the meshes from other 3D programs that you encounter, it's probably best to get used to shared vertices.

Comment: To come back to Luca's case: les vertices can be a big deal in a landscape where vertices can add up very quick. It is also easy to share and prevents holes in the mesh and smooths out errors. It is also easy to generate a mesh either with or without shared vertices.  But... do you HAVE to use shared vertices? No.