# Unwanted artefacts in SceneKit nodes with subdivisionLevel > 0

Tags: ios, macos, 3d, scenekit

Ok, the code for this was quite long and complex so I'm going to have to describe this problem carefully.

Imagine you are creating a 3D object by lathing a set of points around an axis. You now want to generate a spherical texture map for these points. There is now a difficult dichotomy:

If you create a fully cyclical mesh, where the last points are joined to the first points and there are no edges that are not shared by two polygonal facets, then you cannot create a true spherical map. This is because vertices are mapped 1:1 with texture points. The leftmost vertex of the first facet would need to map to a U value of 0; the rightmost vertex of the last facet would map to 1 - but these are the same vertex! The result is that one segment of the mesh is textured with a large portion of the texture map from right to left, whereas all others map from left to right correctly.

[image: Incorrectly mapped texture]

You could theoretically solve this by duplicating the first set of vertices so that they can have different texture coordinates depending on which polygon they relate to, but this surfaces another problem. If I do this and apply a subdivision level to the resulting geometry, an ugly crease appears and the texture seems badly distorted. It's not so obvious on a still image, but look in the bottom right of the image.

[image: Nasty 'pinching']

Ideally I would like to be able to apply a texture map AND subdivision to the same mesh without experiencing these ugly effects. Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The crease in the subdivided model is standard subdivision behavior after duplicating those vertices. In fact, it’s what I and many other 3D modellers do to create creases (opposed to the edge and vertex crease options even scenekit supports). So even though they are “unwanted” by you, it’s expected behavior.

> Imagine you are creating a 3D object by lathing a set of points around an axis. You now want to generate a spherical texture map for these points.

I’m having a hard time imagining why I would want to generate a spherical map for a torus. Spherical mapping is specifically for reflections.

Anyway, the problem is not the subdivision or the map, but the fact you use shared vertices.

> but these are the same vertex!

Right. Instead of adding extra vertices at just the point where the texture basically repeats, you need to feed unique vertices to the SCNGeometry. That way subdivision will work and you can map it as expected.

Comment: Actually it isn't standard behaviour; SceneKit uses crease geometry elements for generating sharp edges, and vertex normals for putting visible sharp lines between facets. The problem was actually that there were some redundant vertices in the profile I was attempting to lathe and this was confusing the subdivision algorithm

Comment: Actually, it IS standard catmull clark subdivision behavior. Scenekit doesn’t use the crease geometry elements unless you use them. It is specifically meant to replace using extra geometry to create creases. 3DS Max and other packages started supported the same functionality many years ago but partly due to the lack of support in file formats using additional geometry that relies on that standard behavior is far more common.

Comment: I think we're talking at cross purposes here; I meant that it isn't standard behaviour to place a crease between lines that share the same vertex positions but not the same vertex indices; when subdividing, two vertices that share the same x/y/z values are treated as being the same vertex unless creases are used. My object currently has no creases and still looks seamless.

Comment: Ah yes, as long as those extra vertices don’t lead to extra faces in the base model. When creases are used they will still be treated as the same vertex, that’s the purpose of the crease features: adding creases without adding the extra geometry. The subdivision in SceneKit is Catmull–Clark subdivision and consists of two main stages, subdivision and smoothing. The crease options allow you to set weights on edges and verts to limit how much they are smoothed, it does not affect the number of edges/lines. Anyway, glad to hear you already worked out your particular issue.

Comment: Yep, it was just a case of good ol' GIGO. Now I need to refine my texture unwrapping process so that it can duplicate vertices when it needs to. That's going to be fun for multi textured objects :D

Comment: Still sounds like it would be easier to move from shared vertices to unique vertices as I suggested in my answer, rather than doing a mix sort of and adjust unwrapping as a workaround based on that. MDLmesh actually had a method to convert geometry with shared vertices to unique ones but it is deprecated (replaced maybe).  Shared vertices are only useful in specific cases which usually does not include texturing dynamically generated objects. See, for example, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843575/do-i-have-to-use-shared-vertices-in-mesh-in-unity

Comment: Depends on your approach really. In my case it is easier to create only one vertex per corner as a working model, then generate duplicates as required by smoothing groups. In any case, having completely unshared vertices may be neat and orderly but it's also inefficient in both memory and processing. You wouldn't see any massive performance hits with low numbers of simple models maybe, but I want a solution that scales.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was actually that there were some redundant vertices in the profile I was attempting to rotate and this was just too much for subdivision to cope with. After removing these, the subdivision looks just fine - so there's probably just a limit to how complex a raw edge you can have on a model before subdivision packs in.