# How can I map a single texture to all sides of a cube using the UV attributes of vertices?

Tags: opengl, rust, 3d, game-development

Currently I am creating a mesh of a cube like this:

```
        //bottom vertices of cube
                    positions.push([ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]);
                    uvs.push([ 0.0, 0.0 ]);

                    positions.push([ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]);
                    uvs.push([ 0.0, 1.0 ]);

                    positions.push([ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]);
                    uvs.push([ 1.0, 1.0 ]);

                    positions.push([ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]);
                    uvs.push([ 1.0, 0.0 ]);


                    //upper vertices of cube
                    positions.push([ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ]);
                    uvs.push([ 0.0, 1.0 ]);

                    positions.push([ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 ]);
                    uvs.push([ 1.0, 1.0 ]);

                    positions.push([ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ]);
                    uvs.push([ 1.0, 0.0 ]);

                    positions.push([ 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ]);
                    uvs.push([ 1.0, 1.0 ]);
```

(I use a texture that is 16x16 pixels big)

But I struggle to map those uv positions, because the maximum number of sides that work are 4.
I would know what to do if there would be 4 vertices for each side (24 in total), but I dont want to do it like this because of performance reasons.

Is there any way of doing this with only 8 vertices per cube?

Comment: performance reasons?  were you joking ?!?!?

Comment: Well I'm planning to create a mesh of a few million of these cubes, so I think this could be some bottleneck with memory.

Comment: a whole million!  :)  I hear you but anyway what is the problem ???

Comment: you really have to do such things with shaders, but, enjoy !

Comment: I tried to to map a single texture to all 6 sides of a cube, but when assigning the texture coordinates of each vertex I am only able to do this for 4 vertices and after that they are overlapping and I dont know what to do now.

Comment: pls see myt answer Bruno!  it may simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the minimal cube has six sides
- each side has TWO TRIANGLES
- you will have TWELVE tris for a minimal cube
- DONT, repeat DO NOT bother trying to share the verts. if for some reason you want to, do that later.
- Simply ensure that each pair of tris (one square) has the correct UV

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36845398/294884

Comment: Ah now It works like a charm, with a bit higher memory usage tho.