# Shader that arranges the texture horizontally

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a generated mesh for stairs (programmatically). The mesh is simple and it cannot be done any more simpler and prettier.

I would like to add a shader that lines the texture horizontally regardless of the direction. Here, as you can see, it is sometimes vertical, sometimes horizontal.

I have auto-generated UVs

```
Shader "Custom/WallShader"
{
    Properties{
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Scale("Scale", float) = 1.0
    }

        SubShader{
            Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma surface surf Standard

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            struct Input {
                float3 worldNormal;
                float3 worldPos;
                float2 uv_MainTex;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;
            float _Scale;

            void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {

                if (abs(IN.worldNormal.x) > 0.5)
                {
                    o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.worldPos.zy * _Scale);
                }
                if (abs(IN.worldNormal.y) > 0.5)
                {
                    o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.worldPos.xz * _Scale);
                }
                if (abs(IN.worldNormal.z) > 0.5)
                {
                    o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.worldPos.xy * _Scale);
                }

                float2 flippedUVs = IN.uv_MainTex;
                flippedUVs.x = flippedUVs.x;
                flippedUVs.y = 1.0 - flippedUVs.y;
                fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, flippedUVs) * _Color;

                o.Emission = o.Albedo;

                o.Albedo = c.rgb;
                o.Alpha = c.a;
            }

            ENDCG
    }
        FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to me you would have to assign the appropriate texture coordinates in your mesh when generating it, possibly duplicating vertices where they should have different UVs depending on the triangle they belong to. I don't see how this is a shader issue, unless I'm missing your point.

Comment: it's just that the UVs are wrong, it's that simple.  if you want the texture to run the other way .. do so.  (ie, change the UVs so it runs the other way)

Comment: note that it would be completely impossible to fix this "in the shader".  the way that you *tell a shader* which way to run a texture, is ... the UVs !!!

Answer (score 1):

- Unless I'm drastically mistaken, you're simply setting the UVs wrong.

Simply do this:

1. For now, don't use your shader.  Very simply set the material to some existing material (perhaps a "wood" or similar look)
2. Run it and see if the UVs are correct

What you are describing is, literally, "the UVs are wrong"

You've got the UVs running the wrong way on those parts, it's a common mistake.

Comment: just FYI, unrelated, be aware of this it might make it easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36845398/294884